# Good practice to add state to an object in this.state array?

Tags: reactjs

**Lets say my this.state looks like this:**

```
getInitialState: function() {
return {
    myArray: [
      {
        someState1: "someValue1"
      }
    ]
   }
},
```

**And I want to achieve this:**

```
modifiedState: function() {
  return {
    myArray: [
      {
        someState1: "someValue1",
        someState2: "someValue2"
      },
      {
        someState3: "someValue3"
      }
    ]
   }
}
```

**What would the best/good practice be to:**

- add an additional state to the existing object in `myArray`
- add a new object to `myArray`.

*My solution to the latter(not sure if the approach is good though):*

```
this.setState({
  myArray: this.state.myArray.concat([newObj])
});
```

Comment: does it HAVE to be an array?

Comment: I rather have it as an array, but whats your thought?

Comment: well your state is already an object, so couldn't you store it without the array? I don't know the exact use case that you have here so it's hard to say

Comment: `Array.concat` is good, since it is not mutating the previous state. Use `.slice` and spread operator if you're going to mutate one of the state.